# Characterizing a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, rf, spectrum-analyzer

I have a capacitor for which I would like to get the output impedance as a function of the frequency. I would like to get something like this:

[image]

For this I have a spectrum analyzer with an output which allows me to set an input voltage on the capacitor at different frequencies:

Here is the equivalent schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvNYYx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Well there is something that I do not understand to obtain Zc:

Suppose I did not connect the capacitor, there is just a voltage divider. So I shoud see Vout = Vin/2, ie -3dB. I have actually 0 dB, so it seems to measure the output volage after the 50R resistor. Nevertheless if that is the case, Vin is always equal to Vout. How does that works? Then I could deduce the transfer function Vin/Vout, get the gain and obtain at least the magnitude of Zc as I would have no information about the phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to work with the assumption that your capacitor is in parallel with the impedance of the analyser input.

The analyser 50 ohm input is calibrated to show the correct voltage when connected to a 50 ohm source, and the output is calibrated to be the correct voltage when connected to a 50 ohm load.

You'll have a voltage divider composed of \$Z_{out}\$ and \$Z_C \parallel Z_{in}\$.  Calculating \$Z_C\$ will mean measuring the voltage at a particular frequency then calculating \$Z_C \parallel Z_{in}\$, then calculating \$Z_C\$ from that given that you know \$Z_{in}\$.

You might consider working with the capacitor in series.  I think the math will be slightly less ugly, and you will get better results for the higher impedance areas.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! I am not sure to understand what you say. First I supposed Zin to be equal to 50 Ohm and Zout equal to 50 Ohm. Then if the voltage appears to be correct when the output is connected to a 50 Ohm resistor (ie with a voltage divider), how can I have the correct Zc by calculating 20log(Vout/Vin). As If I do this calcul I would not have the correct input impedance (50R)

Comment: Assume that the input and output impedances are zero, then draw \$Z_{in}\$ and \$Z_{out}\$ in your diagram as seperate impedances - as through your circuit had real a resistor in series with the output and a real resistor in parallel with the input.  The voltages you measure will be correct.

Comment: Vout/Vin = Zin/(Zin + Zout) ? If Zin = Zout = 50R, I get Vout = Vin/2 ? And I got 0 Vin = Vout

Comment: I'm not explaining this well.  I'll have to think it over and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you :) Good luck ! :D